# How to efficiently compute the exact percentage of non-unique k-mers in a genome for given k?

Tags: genome, software-recommendation, k-mer

I'm looking for some software that can "efficiently" (time and memory) compute the exact percentage of non-unique k-mers in a genome for given k. I don't need the k-mers or the abundances itself, I just need the percentage.

Alternatively, the result could be:

1. the number of different k-mers observed in the genome
2. the number of unique k-mers, i.e. k-mers that occur only once in the genome, **or** the number of non-unique k-mers, i.e., k-mers that occur more than once in the genome.

which can be easily used to compute the requested percentage.

**Requested features:**

- don't count k-mers with ambiguous nucleotides
- count a k-mer and its reverse complement together
- k upto 50 or 100
- for large genomes (upto some GB)
- efficiency

For the study in mind, I like to vary k. Hence, I will run the software several times with different k.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What is your current solution? Which non-efficient programs have you found (To avoid proposing them)? Can't the other answers in the [tag:k-mer] help you to make that program?

Answer (score 5):

You can do all of that with [khmer](http://khmer.readthedocs.io/en/v2.1.1/). For example, `abundance-dist-single.py` produces a file with columns: `k-mer abundance`, `k-mer count`, `cumulative count`, and fraction of total distinct k-mers`. So for question 1 you would sum column 2. For question 2 you would just get the`k-mer count`associated with a`k-mer abundance` of 1.

That package also provides a python API (see the read the docs link above) if you need to customize things more.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that hint. I made a first test of khmer using A.thaliana: `python abundance-dist-single.py -k <k> -b <genome> <out>`. It looks great. It's fast and easy to use. However, I get an error for k > 32. Is there a way to go further than 32?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible with the command line script, but it appears to be [possible in the API](https://github.com/dib-lab/khmer/pull/1511).

Comment: Thanks for that hint, I'll check that. However, I also found out for some examples (and reading the documentation/papers afterwards ;) that it is not exact. Hence, I currently also use the parameters `-N 20 -x 1E7` to avoid too many mistakes. Just in case anyone like to do a similar case study. In addition, I have some problems with some species where khmer states `ERROR: abundance distribution is uniformly zero; nothing to report. Please verify that the input files are valid.` The files seem to be okay and have been used in other analysis. Any ideas?

Comment: No, sorry, I've never seen that error.